# Moving folders with specific files inside them to another folder

Tags: batch, script

So I have a lot of folders with different file names inside them but there is only a variation of file names of about 20. Is it possible to search all folders in a directory for certain file names and then move the folder with the files in it to a different folder?

I'm on Windows 10 and I haven't tried anything. Just a tedious job that i'm falling asleep doing.

I used to play around with batch and vb etc but I haven't for over 10 years so I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Welcome! SuperUser isn't a code-writing service. You'll be more likely to get help if you try a few things yourself first (even just a little bit will help) and let us know where you are running into difficulty.

Comment: the best at the moment i can do is pseudonym. I'm currently at work so i'll have a crack at trying it myself at home. If I get somewhere i'll post the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

This skeleton batch script can do the task:

```
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b /s "ROOT DIR" ^| findstr /i "FILE-NAME"') do (
  echo %%G
  move "%%~dpG" "\path\to\target"
)
```